# Why does stackexchange.com require its own login? Even when you're logged into Meta Stack Exchange?

Tags: feature-request, login, top-bar, stackexchange.com

When I am logged in and looking at any Stack Exchange site (even the ones I do not belong to, and even Meta Stack Exchange) and I select the Stack Exchange dropdown , I see the "Your communities" section and the top 5 sites I've participated in.

But this does not happen on stackexchange.com itself. Instead, all I see is the list of all SE sites in alphabetical order.

This can be really inconvenient, if, for example, I fatfinger Stack Exchange in the topbar again (touchscreens can be a tad oversensitive) and it takes me to stackexchange.com.

Does it have to be this way? Wouldn't it be an easy fix to make the menu's behavior consistent?

**Update**: I noticed that stackexchange.com showed I was not logged in to it. Which doesn't make sense, as I am also not logged in to the dozens of other SE communities I don't belong to, and Your Communities appears for them.

So I went to "log in" under Stackexchange.com itself, and got the login method buttons (I always select Google), and then got the the "confirm and create this account" button. I recalled I'd seen this screen before, but the dire warning

> *If you think you already have a Stack Exchange account, and you were just trying to associate a new OpenID with your existing account, you're in the wrong place.*

always kept me from clicking that button. Well I clicked it this time. Now even stackexchange.com shows Your Communities.

**Update 2**: I changed the title to reflect the true nature of the problem. The original title was *Why does the Stack Exchange browser dropdown not show "Your Commumities"?*

Comment: I can't repro (even with userscripts off) on https://stackexchange.com/ or https://stackexchange.com/sites.

Comment: My recent edit might help. Is it possible you have your stackexchange.com login set up already? Then it masked the problem for you.

Comment: Hmm, downvote two years later, despite the fact that @animuson satisfactorily answered it at the time.

Answer (score 9):

Well because stackexchange.com runs on fairly old login code that is not hooked into the rest of the network, same as Area 51. Right now it's also in a bit of a state of limbo in how it's going to function moving forward. Being able to create an account on stackexchange.com itself is a feature that will be completely retired at some point in the future (last I heard the Users table for stackexchange.com is gonna disappear), because it's just not necessary. Instead, a profile there will only ever exist if you have profiles elsewhere too.

When that happens, the code will likely be updated and drastically simplified to just use the existing login information for the network like all the other sites do. It kind of has to be, given that it won't have a Users table anymore.

Comment: this happens to me too, and area 51. thanks for clarifying why